# Drawing Unicode box in C: the inner one of 2 nested for loop doesn't exit upon hitting the test condition

Tags: c, logical-operators

I'm trying to draw a box from Unicode chars and the problem is that the inner for loop doesn't seem to exit after hitting the condition of reaching 26 iterations, which leaves the output scrambled in one line and split in half.

I've tried replacing the initial values of loop counters with 2 (since it appears as if the first decision condition is skipped due to 0%2 == 0 producing an error, but to no avail.)

I've also tried replacing the spaces with 0 and add some printf tests, but it seems like the main issue is with my inability to decompose this program into modules and I have no idea how it can be performed, giving that the only basic action the function can do is print a character depending on the condition.

Should I try to generalize the edge cases and pass loop counters and the code of printable chars to a function, testing them on each iteration?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

wchar_t edgeLU = 0x250c;
wchar_t vert = 0x2502;
wchar_t leftMid = 0x251c;
wchar_t edgeLB = 0x2514;
wchar_t botMid = 0x2534;
wchar_t horiz = 0x2500;
wchar_t edgeRB = 0x2518;
wchar_t rightMid = 0x2524;
wchar_t edgeRU = 0x2510;
wchar_t upMid = 0x252c;
wchar_t cross = 0x253c;

int i, j;

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
  for (i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 27; j++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            if (j == 0) {
                wprintf(L"%lc", edgeLU);
            }
            else if (j%2 == 1) {
                wprintf(L"%lc", horiz);
            }
            else if (j%2 == 0 && !(j == 0 || j == 26)) {
                wprintf(L"%lc", upMid);
            }
            else {
                wprintf(L"%lc", edgeRU);
            }
        }
        else if (i%2 == 1) {
            if (j%2 == 0) {
                wprintf(L"%lc", vert);
            }
            else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        else if (i%2 == 0 && !(i == 0 || i == 26)) { 
            if (j == 0) {
                wprintf(L"%lc", leftMid);
            }
            else if (j%2 == 1) {
                wprintf(L"%lc", horiz);
            }
            else if (j%2 == 0 && !(j == 0 || j == 26)) {
                wprintf(L"%lc", cross);
            }
            else {
                wprintf(L"%lc", rightMid);
            }
        }
        else if (i == 26) {
            if (j == 0) {
               wprintf(L"%lc", edgeLB);
            }
            else if (j%2 == 1) {
                wprintf(L"%lc", horiz);
            }
            else if (j%2 == 0 && !(j == 0 || j == 26)) {
                wprintf(L"%lc", botMid);
            }
            else {
                wprintf(L"%lc", edgeRB);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

To avoid confusion, ┤ ┴ ├ ┬ are denoted as rightMid, botMid, leftMid and upMid respectively.

That is the output, the program first prints spaces from the (i%2 == 1) condition and newlines, following termination of the inner loop in some haphazard fashion.

[image]

Comment: `continue` is completely superfluous in this case.

Comment: `continue` (as well as `break`) works only for the nearest enclosing loop. Is this your error?

Comment: @thebusybee no, I've forgotten to remove these after trying to fix the problem, it has no effect

Comment: Understood, so please remove these lines from your code.

Comment: Using Win10, mingw-GCC and CMD with code page 65001, it works for me, with the exception that the characters are "+", "-", and "|".

Comment: How about `for (i = 0; i < 27; i++) { /* special case for 0 here */ for(j = 1; j < 27-1; j++){...} /* special case for 26 here */  }` Less branching, less clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In is undefined behaviour to mix wide and narrow character output to the same file. Replace `printf` calls with corresponding `wprintf`.